# Cast iron toilet flange

Tags: toilet, flange, cast-iron

I have a home built in the late '70s with cast iron toilet flanges. It appears to have cast iron flanges with 3" stubs into 4" cast iron pipes.

I haven't seen any information on this setup anywhere. Picture shows that the flange pipe is about 3.5" down.

Is this a possible setup?

I want to cut it below the 3" flange pipe and install a 2" offset flange.

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason for wanting an offset flange?  They can reduce flow.

Comment: Do you have any experience with them? I have used an offset previously with no problems, there are many different designs, particularly the length from the flange to the pipe interface. Some perform the offset within a couple inches others over 4-5 inches.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have removed the screws holding the flange to the floor, it should come out, it might be stuck a bit, but nothing is holding it to the pipe.

It is an insert, possibly with rubber seal, or just wax.

My personal opinion: The 2 inch is OK for sink drains but not for toilet drains.